# Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom for CosmosDb?

Tags: sql-server, azure-cosmosdb, scriptdom

Is there a Microsoft library for parsing and manipulating CosmosDB parse trees a la Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom for SQL server?

Comment: Not sure what, specifically, you're attempting to do but... Cosmos DB is not compatible with Microsoft SQL Server. The SQL API of Cosmos DB is really about the query language; Cosmos DB doesn't have a relational database - it's still a document database.

Comment: For parsing, manipulating, and stringifying parse trees, a la SQL DOM. E.g. one use case would be to parse a query  -> manipulate some nodes -> output to text. E.g. XML DOM, HTML DOM, T-Sql DOM. Not a lot of literature on the subject for T-Sql, but here's one I could find. In this example they are counting statements by type, but you could also do manipulation and stringifying in T-Sql DOM: https://deep.data.blog/2013/04/04/using-the-transactsql-scriptdom-parser-to-get-statement-counts/
T-Sql DOM works great but wondering if there is an equivalent for Cosmos SQL.